# Setting the description for a transfer in Stripe to a Connect Account

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Create a PaymentIntent with the following fields according to the [document](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create).

- application_fee_amount
- transfer_data.destination
- currency
- description (only appears in the platform not for Connect Account)

However, when the connected account receives the transaction, it has a different description.
And the description is only maintained on the platform.

[Image of a express connect account in stripe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13MZI.png)

Where in API I can set the transfer description

Comment: `description` on the Payment Intent object doesn't get populated to the Transfer object and its Destination Charge object. You may follow the guide [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/customize-express-dashboard#destination-charges) to update the `description` of Destination Charge object on the connected account.

Comment: Thanks, what you mentioned solved it!